# Aplicar recursividade num batch script

Tags: windows, batch, ms-dos

Há algum tempo atrás me surgiu a necessidade de utilizar o **Microsoft Office Document Imaging** para converter um modelo de documento criado no Microsoft Word como medida de prevenção anti-cópia do modelo em si (posicionamento, medidas, definições e etc.).

Porém o aplicativo em questão, para quem não conhece, é bem espartano, lento e com umas restrições esquisitas demais para uma *GUI*. Felizmente, a funcionalidade que eu precisava dele, podia ser executada em linha de comando.

Nunca fui muito fã de *batch scripts*, mas mesmo assim optei por criar um arquivo .BAT para automatizar a OCR dos arquivos MDI previamente gerados pela impressora virtual disponibilizada pelo aplicativo.

Como a sintaxe dos *batch scripts* já era coisa antiga quando ganhei meu primeiro computador, nunca me dei ao trabalho de aprender mais do que o necessário para instalar o Windows 98 (na época) e acabei com o seguinte arquivo:

```
@echo off

set filesCount=0

echo Performing OCR over files
echo.

for /r %%i in (*.mdi) do (

set /a filesCount+=1

echo Curent file: %%i

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MODI\11.0\MSPVIEW.EXE" -f %%i

echo OCR performed succesfully
echo.

)

echo.
echo OCR performed over %filesCount% files found
echo.

pause
```

Funciona bem, mas eu tenho de duplicar (ou mover) o arquivo .BAT pra cada diretório antes de executá-lo. E como a execução é aplicada em milhares de arquivos estruturados hierarquicamente em diversos subníveis, isso se torna uma tarefa tediosa *quase* não fazendo valer a pena utilizar o dito script.

É possível modificar esse script para que este opere recursivamente? Dessa forma, eu o armazenaria no diretório-pai de todos os subníveis e executaria uma só vez.

Comment: Testei aqui e a sua bat já esta executando o comando recursivamente, basta executar ela no diretório raiz...

Comment: @Bruno quer executar esse comando recursivamente sobre todo o seu diretório raíz?

Comment: @Jader: Sério? Confesso que nunca experimentei pra ver o que aconteceria. Talvez porque o PC onde usaria é quse movido a carvão. Kyllopardium: Não no diretório raiz, mas a partir de um raiz. Algo como o ./ do *nix. De onde se encontra o .BAT pra frente (ou "pra dentro")

Comment: veja o teste que fiz: [print](http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1zdw16v&s=8#.U-VNYKx0y70) obviamente eu retirei a linha com o executável, mas pode ver que ele pega todos os arquivos em todos os diretórios...

Comment: Vou experimentar só segunda-feira, no serviço. Nesse interim, se quiser responder com esse teste, ficaria feliz em avaliar e marcar como resolvido. Mas só segunda-feira :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com um teste que realizei aqui, sua bat já funciona de forma recursiva:

**teste.bat**

```
@echo off

set filesCount=0

echo Performing OCR over files
echo.

for /r %%i in (*.mdi) do (

set /a filesCount+=1

echo Curent file: %%i


echo OCR performed succesfully
echo.

)

echo.
echo OCR performed over %filesCount% files found
echo.

pause
```

**resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: a linha `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MODI\11.0\MSPVIEW.EXE" -f %%i` foi removida para evitar erros durante a execução, pois não possuo esse executável.

Comment: Caramba... Se eu soubesse que levariam tantos dias até eu poder testar o script não teria dito "segunda feira". Mas funcionou perfeitamente, já era recursivo e eu nem sabia. E o responsável por isso é a flag **/r**